# How to configure UITableView cellForRowAt with 2 sections and multiple cell types

Tags: swift

I have an array of structs, 1 button and 1 custom tableViewCell. I want to position them in 2 sections. Section 1 has the custom tableViewCell. Section 2 has the array followed by the button.
How do I configure these inside cellForRowAt for my UITableView?

Comment: Could you post your code and tell us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered from your question here the code you'll need:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct SomeStruct { var text: String }

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let array = [SomeStruct]()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(Cell1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
        tableView.register(Cell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        return view
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        section == 0 ? 1 : array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! Cell2
            cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row].text
            return cell
        }
    }
}


class Cell1: UITableViewCell { }
class Cell2: UITableViewCell { }

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. how would you add the button to the tableView? I have it as a custom cell as well. 1 struct array, 1 custom cell, 1 custom button cell

Comment: Make a new cell for button and register it. Just like I've shown above for 2 cases. Also, if this answer helped then upvote and mark as the right answer.

Comment: Could you edit that code sample to reflect this 3 cell configuration? This is specifically what I dont understand about this. 

Comment: I think you need to do more research and find a solution for your self according to your logic. I would suggest you check out youtube for table view multiple cell tutorials.